# Paypal adaptive payment php

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have this problem. I've follow this tutorial -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzRR1i-F_VA

and after setting everything, I have some problem with getting through the authentification process. And After some research on authentification, I've tested this -> https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

At some point in the process (Making test requests), I've tested it in a bash console, and my userid, password and signature worked. So I figure that the problem was in the code I was using.

So here's the code:

```
<?php
class PaypalTest extends CComponent{

public $api_user = "**********************";
public $api_pass = "***********";
public $api_sig = "**************************";
public $app_id = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
public $apiUrl = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/';
public $paypalUrl="https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";
public $headers;

public function __construct(){
    $this->headers = array(
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".$this->api_user,
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".$this->api_pass,
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".$this->api_sig,
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".$this->app_id,
    );
}

public function getPaymentOptions($paykey){

}
public function setPaymentOptions(){

}
public function _paypalSend($data,$call){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl.$call);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $this->headers);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
    return $response;

}
public function splitPay(){

    // create the pay request
    $createPacket = array(
        "actionType" =>"PAY",
        "currencyCode" => "USD",
        "receiverList" => array(
            "receiver" => array(
                array(
                    "amount"=> "1.00",
                    "email"=>"********@hotmail.com"
                ),
                array(
                    "amount"=> "2.00",
                    "email"=>"********@gmail.ca"
                ),
            ),
        ),
        "returnUrl" => "http://test.local/payments/confirm",
        "cancelUrl" => "http://test.local/payments/cancel",
        "requestEnvelope" => array(
            "errorLanguage" => "en_US",
            "detailLevel" => "ReturnAll",
        ),
    );

    $response = $this->_paypalSend($createPacket,"Pay");
}
}
```

And here's the call:

```
$payment = new PaypalTest();
$payment->splitPay();
```

Quite simple, but something is not working. And I'm not really familiar with Curl so I thought you guys could help me

P.S: I'm in sandbox mode

Thanks

Carl

Comment: What isn't working? What error do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645381/paypal-adaptive-payment-php 
Can any one help me to complete the payment steps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change CURLOPT_HEADER to CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER